# Current blockchain hot topics in research

Tags: blockchain, academic-research

I'm looking for a research project for my master thesis in software engineering and computer science and i'm willing to research the blockchain technology. What are the current open issues and/or hot topics regard blockchains?

EDIT: I can see my question is way too generic, i just wanted to specify i read about 20 papers on the topic and i'm more concerned about the dencentralization aspect of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's scalability. The cost to generate a block is getting more and more expensive. Couple months ago, CryptoKitties caused Ethereum network congestion due to the surge of transactions. For real world application, I think blockchain must be able to handle high volume of transaction. This can be achieved by reducing the cost to generate a block. AFAIK, some blockchains are developing [proof-of-stake algorithms](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proof_of_Stake) replace the old proof-of-work one.

You may interested in [Ouroboros proof-of-stake algorithm](http://cardanohub.org/), which is implemented by Cardano. Ethereum is also working on their own implementation - Casper

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at this [long list of Bitcoin's weaknesses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Weaknesses). Since your question is aimed at blockchains in general, why not also take a look at [Ethereum's list of problems](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Problems).

Answer (score 0):

Cartel theory may be interesting to research since you say you are concerned about decentralization. Bitcoin is carefully considered to avoid cartels and I know that it is a real consideration given when discussing any potential change. You may enjoy listening in on the [[bitcoin-dev]](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/bitcoin-dev) mailing list.